# I sensed a lot of people disagreed

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have the text:

> I took a deep breath. "Trying to keep us from praying at school is dumb, but I honestly think Mr. Bookman was just scared and did something on impulse. He's new, and I think once he knows the truth about what you can and can't do, he'll follow it".
>   I sensed a lot of people disagreed, but when I faced Pastor Andy he was smiling.

Can you explain to me why the author was using

1) "I sensed a lot of people disagreed".

Why was not:

2) "I sensed that a lot of people were disagreed".

Can you tell me the differenece between 1) and 2)?

Comment: Same meaning. "that" can and is usually omitted when introducing noun clauses (known as "content clauses" by some grammarians).

Comment: The "that" doesn't make any difference, I'll agree, but the "were" certainly does.  Specifically, it makes the sentence not make any sense.  Disagreed is something the people *did*, not something they *were*.